# ValueError :Setting an array element with a sequence using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-3.5

I have this piece of code in python

```
data = np.empty(temp.shape)
maxlat = temp.shape[0]
maxlon = temp.shape[1]
print(maxlat,maxlon)

for i in range(0,maxlat) :
    for j in range(0,maxlon):
        data[i][j] = p_temperature(pr,temp[i][j])
```

When I run this code in Python 3.5, I get this error

```
ValueError : setting an array element with a sequence
```

The value of `maxlat` is `181` and the value of `maxlon` is `360`.

The shape of `temp` array is `(181,360)`

I also tried the suggestion in the comments:

```
for i in range(0,maxlat) :
    for j in range(0,maxlon):
        data[i][j] = temp[i][j]
```

But I get the same error.

Comment: What does `ptemperature` do?

Comment: Based on the error, it looks that `p_temperator` does not return a scalar, but a numpy array itself.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - it just returns a number given two inputs p and temp

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I checked it does return a scalar.

Comment: Can you provide sample of `temp` please?

Comment: @Nuageux - how do you want sample of temp ? In the question or as a external file ?

Comment: In the question. But please, just a sample (for example 5x5 not full 181x360), basically enough for us to reproduce your problem and help you solved it

Comment: You have to add prints to check values - dtype, shape, `temp[0,0]`, etc.  I don't think it's a deep problem, but we can't guess remotely.

Comment: the only thing we can tell is that you trying to create an array from a list that isn't shaped like a multi-dimensional array

Comment: Another possible cause for this error message is trying to use a string as an element in an array of type float:

Comment: @ADITYA No, that throws an `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` exception. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the exception you get it seems likely that `temp` is an `object` array containing sequences. You could simply use [`numpy.empty_like`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty_like.html):

```
data = np.empty_like(temp)  # instead of "data = np.empty(temp.shape)"
```

This creates a new empty array with the same shape and dtype - *like* your original array.

---

For example:

```
import numpy as np

temp = np.empty((181, 360), dtype=object)
for i in range(maxlat) :
    for j in range(maxlon):
        temp[i][j] = [1, 2, 3]
```

With the new approach it works:

```
data = np.empty_like(temp)
maxlat = temp.shape[0]
maxlon = temp.shape[1]
print(maxlat, maxlon)

for i in range(maxlat) :
    for j in range(maxlon):
        data[i][j] = temp[i][j]
```

And this `temp` array also reproduces the exception on your original code sample:

```
data = np.empty(temp.shape)  # your approach
maxlat = temp.shape[0]
maxlon = temp.shape[1]
print(maxlat, maxlon)

for i in range(maxlat) :
    for j in range(maxlon):
        data[i][j] = temp[i][j]
```

throws the exception:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.