# Change dtype of ndarray from object to float?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, tuples, python-itertools

I found a strange 3D ndarray(see attached file) that does not show the shape of the last dimension and dtype change(asarray nor astype from 'object' to np.float) does not work.

[file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzxiDcBmvq-INGxuSDlwS295WW8)

It is an ndarray of ('object','object','float64')dtype for each dimension and the actually shape is (2,3,24) but shape is shown as (2,3), which means 24 dimensional array in (2,3) does not count.

When I try .asarray or .astype to make this array as 'dtype=np.float' for every dimension, I got an error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Unfortunately, none of the methods previously discussed in here do not work for this case.
[ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)

[Numpy ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. This message may appear without the existing of a sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310347/numpy-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-this-message-may-app)

[Error: Setting an array element with a sequence. Python / Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803256/error-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-python-numpy)

[ValueError :Setting an array element with a sequence using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085495/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-using-numpy)

[Python Numpy Error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521680/python-numpy-error-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)

How can I change the dtype of the array into np.float for all dimension so that I can utilise typical np operations? Thank you.

*I met this problem by extracting some data points from python's collection.deque library.
I stored a series of tuples of dtype (ndarray-float, bool), and pick a few as an ndarray via

`array = np.asarray(list(itertools.islice())).`

I extract the float-side elements by doing `state_array = array[:,:,0]`. I wanted to make state_array into purely np.float dtype-d ndarray for every dimension but couldn't. What's happening is that this state_array has 'object' as datatype `state_array.asarray()` nor `np.array(state_array)` do not work with the error-code below.

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: So it looks like you have a 2x3 array of objects.  Are all those objects arrays (or lists) of shape (24,)?  If they are, we can join them into one 3d arrays with a concatenate.  But if some differ in size/shape we can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your download, I can load the array:

```
In [850]: data =np.load('../Downloads/strange_array.npy',encoding='latin1')
In [851]: data.shape
Out[851]: (2, 3)
```

the elements are all the same shape and dtype, so they can be joined into a 3d array:

```
In [852]: [i.shape for i in data.flat]
Out[852]: [(24,), (24,), (24,), (24,), (24,), (24,)]
In [853]: [i.dtype for i in data.flat]
Out[853]: 
[dtype('float64'),
 dtype('float64'),
 dtype('float64'),
 dtype('float64'),
 dtype('float64'),
 dtype('float64')]
```

that joining is easiest if we flatten out that 2x3 shape:

```
In [854]: np.stack(data.ravel()).shape
Out[854]: (6, 24)
In [855]: np.stack(data.ravel()).reshape(2,3,24)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I absolutely on automatically picking arrays to a new ndarray.